Distinction body / individual: was Foucault the first to make it? Did he coin this expression?
You now often hear people talking about the body where one could say the individual or the people ("les gens" in French).
I've found in Foucault's Discipline & punish the following sentence:

The body now serves as an instrument or intermediary : if one intervenes upon it to imprison it, or to make it work, it is in order to deprive the individual of a liberty that is regarded both as a right and as property.

(see Discipline & punish at page 11)
so I'm now wondering, was Foucault the first one to make such a distinction?, or was it used before?
Thanks.

Oh. I thought the Dilbert comic came up with in-duh-vidual.

Body is a central concept in F's philosophy, but it has a tradition in philosophy since Descartes and La Mettrie's Homme machine (1748):

L’Homme est une Machine si composée, qu’il est impossible de s’en faire d’abord une idée claire, conséquemment de la définir. C’est pourquoi toutes les recherches que les plus grands Philosophes ont faites à priori, c’est à dire, en voulant se servir en quelque sorte des aîles de l’Esprit, ont été vaines. Ainsi ce n’est qu’à posteriori, ou en cherchant à demêler l’Ame, comme au travers des Organes du corps [body], qu’on peut, je ne dis pas, découvrir avec évidence la nature même de l’Homme, mais atteindre le plus grand degré de probabilité possible sur ce sujet.

What is specific with Foucault is the idea that the modern self is constituted by means of various disciplinary mechanisms acting on the body.
See Marcelo Hoffman, Disciplinary power, Ch.two of: Dianna Taylor (editor), Michel Foucault: Key Concepts (Acumen Publishing, 2011), page 28:

The concept of disciplinary power concerns individuals. A s Foucault
notes with reference to what he takes to be the ideal exercise of this
power, "We are never dealing with a mass, with a group, or even,
to tell the truth, with a multiplicity: we are only ever dealing with
individuals" (Psychiatric Power: Lectures at the College de France, 2006). However, in opposition to political theories which take the individual as a given for the purpose of constructing sovereignty, as in the notable case of Thomas Hobbes's version of the social contract, Foucault sets about showing that the
individual first and foremost amounts to a construction of disciplinary
power. The individual is an effect of this form of power rather than
the raw material upon which it impinges. Foucault writes, "Discipline 'makes' individuals; it is the specific techniques of a power that regards
individuals as obj ects and as instruments of its exercise" (Discipline and Punish: The Birth of the Prison, 1979: 170).
As a first approximation, we can therefore say that disciplinary power
produces individuals as its objects, objectives and instruments.
Disciplinary power yields such effects by targeting bodies [emphasis mine]. The targeting of bodies may not seem terribly unique, especially in light of Foucault's sweeping assertion that "what is essential in all power is that ultimately its point of application is always the body."

We may say that the "new practices" of control adopted during the eighteenth century act on the individual controlling the body vs the traditional ones used by e.g. the Church: prayer, confession, that acted mainly on the soul.

OK - thanks for your answer; but my question is: using the word "body" in this sense, had it been done before Foucault? If yes, who did?

@seb I do not think that he is using the term "body" with a meaning different from the human body.

No indeed - I mean "body" as opposed to "individual [person]".
In this very sense, had "body" already been used before?

In most of modern philosophy before the 20th century, body has been used aplenty meaning the physical ("mechanical") body as opposed to mind/soul. The construction of a "person" as an integration of body and (rational) soul is present at least since the 18th century.
What is somewhat novel with Foucault is the idea that one aspect of personhood besides their bodily existence and rational mind (which Foucault would reject) is some socially constructed aspect he calls "individual", which is then the primary social and political actor and addressee. I think it would be wrong to equal person with individual. From Durkheim and Mead, one of his lessons has been that personhood, as the integration of physical body and individual (and arguably lived/phenomenological body), is culturally relative due to different cultures forming different individuals. The person is the body and all its "individuals", if you like (ref. Mental Illness and Personality).
As of whether he was the first who expressed these kinds of concepts (with similar yet different labels)? My take would be NO since similar concepts and ideas have been expressed as early as 1931 in Helmuth Plessner's Macht und menschliche Natur (Political Anthropology).
